# Comparing values in a stl list<> that is populated with a class

Tags: list, class, stl, c++-cli

I've been playing around with my code, trying to better it and im stuck a this part.

I have the following header

Funcionario.h

```
class Funcionario
{
private:
std::string Userid;
std::string Nome;
std::string Sobrenome;
std::string Email;
std::string Pass;

public:
Funcionario(std::string Userid, std::string Nome, std::string Sobrenome, std::string Email, std::string Pass);
~Funcionario(void);

string GetUserID()  { return Userid;    }
string GetName()    { return Nome;  }
string GetSName()   { return Sobrenome; }
string GetEmail()   {return Email;  }
string GetPass()    { return Pass;  } 
};
```

And this is my form, note that it's not the entire form, just the part that matters;

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include "Funcionario.h"



Form1(void)
{
InitializeComponent();
//
//TODO: Add the constructor code here
//
LF = new list<Funcionario>();
}

//Button click    
list<Funcionario>::iterator it1 = find(LF->begin(), LF->end(), ID); //*Searches for ID
```

When i try to run this it says that there is no suitable converter to tipe Funcionario. 
Any help would be apreciated and thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list<Funcionario>::iterator it1 = find_if(LF->begin(), LF->end(),
  [&ID](const Funcionario& f) { return f.GetUserId() == ID; } );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying Igor, but it gives a little error in the [&ID]. Error: "local lambda is not allowed in a member function of a managed class" any idea what this is?

Comment: This means you are not using C++ but a different, distantly related, language called C++/CLI. I'm not familiar with it beyond the fact of its existence.